# Datatrigger cannot see default property value in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display a control in the xaml if the property `ConnectionStatus` is True, this property have the following structure:

```
    private bool _connectionStatus = true;
    public bool ConnectionStatus
    {
        get { return _connectionStatus; }
        set
        {
            _connectionStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and as you can see this property have `true` as default value.
Then in my xaml window I've used a `DataTrigger` to show or hide the control based on the `ConnectionStatus` value. What I did so far:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
     <StackPanel.Style>
         <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionStatus}" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <Ellipse Fill="#FF51FF00" Height="17" Width="17" Margin="0,5,0,0" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="White" />
 </StackPanel>
```

now the problem's that the `Ellipse` simply not showing, 'cause the whole `StackPanel` is collapsed, but it shouldn't 'cause the property value is `True`, when I set `False` in the xaml code, I get the `Ellipse` displayed correctly.

**Note that:** this situation only happen on the preview window, if I start the application all working good. Someone could please explain me why in the preview the trigger doesn't read the property value correctly?

**Further information**

the window that have the `StackPanel` have the `DataContext` declared in this way:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.MVVM.ViewModels"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ConnectionVM}">
```

then the `ConnectionVM` have this implementation:

```
public class ConnectionVM: ViewModel
{
     //the property defined on top
}
```

and the `ViewModel` have this structure:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably your OnPropertyChanged is never fired and therefore the datatrigger is not updated? The effect could be different in runtime.

Comment: @mm8 please see my edit, for Chrille, the `OnPropertyChanged` event is fired, but this problem is related on the preview not on the execution time.

Comment: I don't think the designer supports data triggers.